# jest ignore specific line in react native test

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I want to ignore the covarage of a line I specified while writing unit test with gesture in my react native project.

I tried,

```
/* c8 ignore next */

/* istanbul ignore next line */
```

my code like as below

```
         <TextInput
              multiline
              value={decode(commentText)} --> here i want to ignore 
              numberOfLines={6}
              maxLength={240}
              onChangeText={(value) => setCommentText(value)}
              placeholder={'share'}
            />
```

when i try these it still tries to cover that line any solition or idea?